# I am passing data from view to conntroller using ajax method call but data becomes null when it comes to action method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
function UserLogin() {

        var username = $("#txtUsername").val();
        var passcode = $("#txtPassword").val();
        alert(username);

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("Login", "UserAccount")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'username': username, 'passcode': passcode },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.username);

        }
    });
```

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string passcode)
{
if (IsValidUser(username, passcode))
{
return RedirectToAction("UserInfo", "UserAccount");
}
else
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your Username or password is invalid");
}
return View();
}

```
    private bool IsValidUser(string username, string passcode)
    {
        string Query = "Select Count(ID) from Users where Username =" + username + " and PassCode = "+ passcode +"";
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(NpgSQLHelper.ExecuteScalar(Utility._connectionstring, System.Data.CommandType.Text, Query));
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With postman the endpoint works correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`
or **modify contentType** to `contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` can work fine.